# Which of these words comes after a city name? Which or Where

Tags: subordinate-clauses

> This summer, Antalya, ______ a lot of people spend their vacation in, will be more crowded due to the new music festival.
>
> a. where
> b. that
> c. when
> d. which

I picked A but the answer key shows D.

Comment: The fact that the answer key shows D should tell you that D is probably right and your choice was wrong. Have you tried to figure out _why_ that may be? When asking a question here, you should always first do some research of your own and include that in the question itself, and then specific _precisely why that did not answer your question_; in this case, _why_ do you think A would be correct or D incorrect? What logic did you apply that led you to this conclusion?

Comment: It would be A if it said _spend their vacation_, but instead it's _spend their vacation **in**_. The object of a preposition has to be a noun phrase, like _which_, and not an adverbial like _where_.

Comment: Was just typing that! :o)

Comment: The sentence with "which" is infelicitous. Is it from a Turkish book about learning English? Almost everyone would say "This summer, Antalya, where a lot of people spend their vacation, will be more crowded due to the new music festival".

Comment: This question does not appear to be about English language and usage within the scope defined in the help center. It is predicated on the misconception that one of the options is acceptable, shows no sign of research, and would not be appropriate on a site aimed at linguists even if the test was not flawed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, **which** is the correct choice.

You can use *where* if you reword slightly as in:

- ..., [place], **where** a lot of people spend their vacation, ...
- ..., [place], **which** a lot of people spend their vacation **in**, ...

As @tchrist pointed out, it might be clearer to rephrase it slightly more:

- ..., [place], a city **where** a lot of people spend their vacation, ...

I know it doesn't help answer your original question, but it is poorly structured overall (it reads like *journalese*, which I detest). I think I would turn the whole thing around and write:

- Antalya, **a city popular  for vacations**, will be **busier** [or *extra crowded*, which isn't quite as grammatical but people will understand] this summer due to a new music festival.

It's not like there's only one music festival from the perspective of non-residents reading about it, after all.

Comment: Or: “..., a city where a lot of people spend their vacation”.

Comment: @tchrist He gave that case already. where//or which + in.

Comment: @Lambie no, Tom is right. I had considered adding that (as I would, probably, if writing something like this) as I was focussed on illustrating the difference in wording to OP.

Answer (score 1):

> This summer, Antalya, ______ a lot of people spend their vacation in, will be more crowded due to the new music festival.

Notice the word "in". That requires the "which".

It's actually a poorly structured sentence in my opinion.

A more elegant and correct version would be:

> This summer, Antalya, *in which* a lot of people spend their vacation <s>in</s>, will be more crowded due to the new music festival.

or, even better in my view:

> This summer, Antalya, *where* a lot of people spend their vacation <s>in</s>, will be more crowded due to the new music festival.

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence tells me 'this summer' has been given the name 'Antalya'.

> In Antalya, where many people spend their vacations, it will be
>   especially crowded this summer due to the new music festival.

Comment: Maybe not the "right" answer but it is funny. Thanks for brightening the place up a bit